# Angular.JS + Jade = angular not processing jade's embedding iframe

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, embed, pug

So I am trying to embed a video using jade and angular.js. I try using the following code in jade, but angular didn't process it, while when i type `p {{video.updated_time}}` there is no problem, but the following code does not work

```
iframe(ng-src="{{video.embedLink}}")
```

I also tried writing an angular directive. This is the code of the directive

```
app.directive('embedDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div style="height:315px;width:560px;"><iframe class="video"     style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'
    };
});
```

And I use this in my jade file: `div(embed-directive, url="video.embedLink")` . None of the solutions seem to work for me. Only difference is that when I use a directive, no error for failed embed processing is shown in the console, but the src in the iframe is empty. No brackets no equation mark, just src in the middle of the iframe. Also in the iframe there seem to be html, head and body tags, which DO NOT exist in my directive. I am pretty confused

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with jade. It sounds like a sanitization issue (Angular zutomatically sanitizes resource URLs and other stuff to protect your app). Try to include `ngSanitize` in your app (import `angular-sanitize.js` and declare `'ngSanitize'` as a dependency of you app).

Comment: I found a getaround, just waiting enough time to post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like angular is trying to protect the application from foreign link, therefore one will need to 'trustify' a link. This is what I found the easiest. Simply add this function in the controller

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
```

and then this is how one should use a `<iframe></iframe>` with jade

```
iframe(ng-src="{{trustSrc(video.embedLink)}}", src="", widht="560", height="315", frameborder="0", allowfullscreen)
```

Of course, `$sce` should be in the controller dependencies.

Comment: Easiest doesn't mean best or safest :)